# Does the word 'weights' refer to the values fitted to the convolution filters in a CNN?

Tags: filter, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm getting overwhelmed by copious vocabulary and too many conflicting uses of words across various descriptions of a CNN.

Basically, what does the word 'weight' mean?

Bonus vocabulary question: Is a 'neuron' the same as a 'weight'?

Answer (score 0):

Weights are a variable of which the inputs of a neuron is multiplied by, before being used. That's basically it.

A neuron consists of two parts, the first one sums up all the inputs, and the second one is an activation function.

Comment: So a neuron consists of two functions? And weights are inputs to these functions?

Comment: Well, yeah? i guess you can call them functions. Weights are not the input though, they just multiply the input by a value before the neuron uses it, (A weight's value changes during training by the way)